# Automatically resize TableLayoutPanel row when window is resized

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, tablelayoutpanel

I have a simple 1x3 `TableLayoutPanel`. I want to achieve a very simple thing: When the window is resized, resize the middle row and keep top and bottom ones the same. I tried doing the logical thing, which is setting rigid top and bottom row sizes and autosize for the middle row. Unfortunately, it's the bottom row that resizes.

```
// 
// tableLayoutPanel1
// 
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.topPanel, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.middlePanel, 0, 1);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.bottomPanel, 0, 2);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 24F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1102, 492);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 19;
```

All of the inner panels have Dock set to Fill and default anchors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change middle row to 100% percent, which will tell the system that middle row will fill any gap left. So change this (I believe its your designer.cs):

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
```

to:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
```

Check [`TableLayoutPanel.RowStyle` from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles.aspx):

> 1. Rows with RowStyle set to Absolute are considered first, and their fixed heights are allocated.
> 2. Rows with RowStyle set to AutoSize are sized to their contents.
> 3. Remaining space is divided among rows withRowStyle set to Percent.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set absolute sizes for the first and third rows:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height = 100;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[2].Height = 100;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[2].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
```

To be sure the second  (middle) row should have `SizeType = SizeType.Percent` and `Height = 100`. Your `Form` should have maximum `Height` of 200.

Answer (score 1):

i did

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
```

and it worked...
by setting the anchor top and bottom i made sure that if resize the row will grow bigger/smaller, and by making the first and 3rd rows absolute size and the middle percentage size i made sure only the middle will grow bigger/smaller